# What are the pros and cons of grouping multiple table together in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, database, nosql

The problem is Cassandra cannot handle a lot of tables per cluster (> 1000). I was looking for any means to reduce the number of tables, and one of them was grouping multiple tables that share the same structure to gether.

Let say if we have two table **A** and **B**

```
create table A (
    key text,
    value text,
    primary key(key)
)
```

and

```
create table B (
    key text,
    value text,
    primary key(key)
)
```

We can group them together by adding one more partition key

```
create table Shared (
    original_table_name text,    // either 'A' or 'B'
    key text,
    value text,
    primary key(original_table_name, key)
)
```

My question is, is it a good pattern and what are the consequences of modelling data this way?

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate what you mean by alot of tables, because our production is running with 50+ tables, and I don't see any issue with it.

Anyways, if your application is using atlot of tables, then most probable cause of it it, normalized table. In cassandra you should always create denormalized tables, because of no join facility. Cassandra is built for very fast writes, so, you can count on it and not worry about that.

Now regarding the new design, I don't see any problem with that, only thing is your partition key should be combination of (table_name, key) and not just table_name so that it will be evenly distributed across nodes.
And ofcourse to query each time, you will have to specify table_name + key.

Comment: Question updated. I'm dealing with 1000+ tables, because we are hosting multiple apps (and denormalization definitely plays a role here). The motivation for this question is to reduce the number of tables so that we don't need to make many extra clusters to host them.